# Detect single or multiline query result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, metadata

First query always returns a single line result:

```
SET FMTONLY ON;

SELECT 123 AS col1

SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

The second query returns a multiline result:

```
SET FMTONLY ON;

SELECT col1 FROM table1

SET FMTONLY OFF;
```

Both queries return table columns.

Can I detect whether the query returns a single line or multi line result?

Comment: Not without executing a query, what are you actually trying to do here? Seems like it is probably an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/179361)

Comment: According to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=When%20FMTONLY%20is%20ON%20%2C%20a,The%20default%20value%20is%20OFF%20.), both queries will return only column names, since `FMTONLY` is set to `ON`, so neither of them will return any rows at all. That being said, the documentation also recommend not using `set fmtonly on`

Comment: fmtonly not required. Maybe there is another command?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how many rows a query _would_ return if you executed it, but without actually running it? In the general case the answer would be "no", you have to run the query to get a row count.

Answer (score 0):

The system variable @@rowcount returns the number of rows affected by the last statement executed within scope.  If the statement is SELECT then it returns the number of rows selected.

Execute these 2 statements:

```
SELECT 123 AS col1;
select @@rowcount rows_selected;
```

Returns

```
col1
123
----------
rows_selected
1
```

Execute these 2 statements:

```
SELECT 123 AS col1 union all
SELECT 456 AS col1;
select @@rowcount rows_selected;
```

Returns

```
col1
123
456
----------
rows_selected
2
```

Comment: Anyway that's how to detect how many rows resulted.